# I set all constraints but I still get a weird behavior. Even in the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a view with multiple objects.
* I deleted all my `constraints` and started from scratch and started from top to bottom. making sure every object is "blue" and that every object has the following constraints: X-coordinate, Y Coordinate, Width & Height.
There are 3 container views in the view controller. 2 of them are overlayed on top of each other. These have no issues. However the one on the top behaves weirdly in `iPhone XR`, but not in `iPhone XS`. Eve in the storyboard it has a weird behavior. See picture attached.

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Yk3.png)

As you can see, the `frame` of the `UIView` is outlined in the blue brackets, but it is only drawing partially INSIDE those frames.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I understand the description but what is your expected behaviour? For the bottom UIView? For the frame to overlay? You should also post the result and expected outcome for us to help you.

Comment: I want the Top UIView to be 10 pixels away from the right edge. As you can see it's blue frame is 10 pixels away, however the UIview itself is like 15 or 20 (and it shows when i build on XR). Additionally, the view it's displaying gets "eaten" up, basically most things in that view are contrained to center but dont appear in the center, they shift around 10 - 15 pixels (same offset as the view)

Comment: Ahh.... okay then. It could be because of the safe area. Try setting it to be 10 pixels away from the superview instead. 

[https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/]